# Laravel Form Request issue with validation

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to use form request in my REST API built using laravel 5.2. My controller is

```
public function save(SbcEntityFormRequest $request)
{
        $requestData = Input::all();
        try {
            list($success, $message) = $this->sbcService->saveSbcEntity($requestData);
            if ($success) {
                return $this->successJsonResponse($request, ['id' => $message]);
            }

            return $this->errorJsonResponse($request, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, [$message]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            AppLog::write($e);
            $message = [config('messages.save_failed')];

            return $this->errorJsonResponse($request, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $message);
        }
}
```

My form request is

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class SbcEntityFormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;

    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'logo' => 'Required',
            'bio' => 'Required|Max:150'
        ];
    }
}
```

My validation rules are never called. I put a die statement in authorize() function and it is neither called. When I printed $request->all() in the controller it shows empty array. Any Idea on what is wrong here?

Comment: Please show the form and make sure that you import the FormRequest in your controller